# Force one site to http with www and force secure-email folder to https with www

Tags: php, regex, html, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to write a **RewriteRule** for my **.htaccess** file. My Condition is following, **Force All user on my website to HTTP with www and force secure-email folder to only https with www.**

Any ideas on how to write this RewriteRule?

Comment: Please, I need an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something similar to this (adapt it for your need):

```
# non-www to www
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'domain.com'">
  Redirect 301 "/" "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.domain.com/"
</If>
# secure url for secure-email uri
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ ^/secure-email$">
  Redirect 301 ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
</If>
# unsecure url for secure-email uri
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ ^/secure-email$" && "%{HTTPS} = 'on'">
  Redirect 301 ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
</ElseIf>
```

FYI: this works only with Apache version >=2.4 or else you have to use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
more details can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#elseif) to adapt the rules above.

But I highly recommend setting all the website over HTTPS (HTTPS is a requirement for many new browser features, particularly those required for Progressive Web Apps)

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide more details please.